# User profile synchronization service instance turning off

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, profile-sync

I have setup synchronization service and successfully imported accounts from AD. I also have configured incremental synchronization to be run every hour (there are frequent updates and/or account modifications made by another system).

Thing is that from time to time `User profile synchronization service instance` turns off, and incremental sync isn't performed and our system is outdated. I have to start synchronization service instance and it all works again.

Any ideas why service instance might be turning off? I don't have any clues on time when this is happening. I'm thinking of powershell script which could be run every few hours and check whether service instance is running and if not, turn it on again. But I'd prefer to prevent it from disabling again.

Answer (score 2):

A common problem is people removing the farm account from local administrators on the servers, due to security.

This is a good practise, but if you perform backups using the SharePoint methods (powershell/central admin) it'll unprovision UPS before backup to get a stable snapshot of the farm and then try to provision it again after the backup, but fail due to farm account not being local admin.

Comment: We are performing backups using sharepoint's built in mechanisms, but as far I can tell, farm account is a local administrator (I know it's bad and should be corrected).

Comment: It's bad, but can't be corrected if you want UPS to work. Sorry that wasn't the right answer :-(

Comment: That's still really good info to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would occasionally get my synchronization a having issues and would just rebuild the damn thing: http://iedaddy.com/2010/01/user-profile-synchronization-service-stuck-at-starting-sharepoint-2010/

I've had it stop because of:

Local admin taken away
OS patches
Stalled timer Jobs

Just remember... 2. Confirm that the user account performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group. If you are using a Windows Server 2003 AD DS forest, the Service Administrator account must be a member of the Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access group for the domain with which you are synchronizing. Now restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

First, is it possible for you add some monitoring to track if the following services are restarting at some point?

- Forefront Identity Manager Service
- Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service

Second, Try clearing the configuration cache

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx

Third, make sure "Web Service Application Pool" in all servers are running without any failure.